# CreateChildControls() for WinForms

Tags: winforms, custom-controls, windows-forms-designer

I have a property of type `List<MyItems>` with the `DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)` attribute in MyCustomControl class. This allows the collection to be properly serialized to the designer file.

How do I initialize this collection such as when the user drags MyCustomControl on the Form, 3 items are added automatically? Exactly how the standard TabControl does with TabPages.

I guess that a method like the ASP.NET CreateChildControls() should exist for WinForms to accomplish this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered you need to implement your own designer and override the `InitializeNewComponent()` method to create child controls and eventually the `InitializeExistingComponent()` to edit them.